# Django: Foreign Key to a partitioned table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, database-partitioning

I have used [architect](https://architect.readthedocs.io/) to partition an existing table.

```
@architect.install('partition', type='range', subtype='integer', constraint='100', column='id')
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

The project model was used as a foreign key to another model.

```
class ProjectChangeLog(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

After partitioning, I could not add any ProjectChangeLog objects. It says:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "logging_projectchangelog" violates foreign key constraint 
DETAIL:  Key (project_id)=(231) is not present in table "project_project"
```

Comment: There are a couple of additional steps on the partition-specific documentation page. Did you export your settings file with `$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=path_to_settings.py` and run `architect partition --module path-to-model.module`?

Comment: @souldeux: I have done that. Partition tables are created.

Comment: This is a limitation of postegresql < 12. It's now supported.

Comment: So I should rephrase... It's supported, only if the table is partitioned on the PK. Otherwise, you need to use this hack in conjunction with it.

https://www.depesz.com/2018/11/04/foreign-key-to-partitioned-table-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

One of the Limitations of partitions is that you can't have foreign keys pointing to them. One workaround for this is to use custom constraints to mimic ForeignKey behavior. This [method](https://www.depesz.com/2018/10/02/foreign-key-to-partitioned-table/) can help you.